# Completely stuck on a new mariadb-server initialization

Tags: freebsd, mariadb

New install of `mariadb-server` 5.5.38 on `FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE-p5 amd64` refuses to start.

Currently refusing to start for this reason:

```
140808 14:12:28 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
140808 14:12:28 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
140808 14:12:28 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
140808 14:12:28 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' (errno: 13)
140808 14:12:28 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Can't find file: './mysql/host.frm' (errno: 13)
140808 14:12:28 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/db/mysql/milicent.ericx.net.pid ended
```

And, of course, the referenced `mysql_upgrade` refuses to run because the server is not running (so I'm ignoring the `plugin.frm` error for the time being).

Everything I can find suggests that `host.frm` should be created first-start in the `datadir`. Obviously `mysqld` understands that `datadir=./mysql`. This in spite of the fact that `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf` specifies `datadir`:

```
[mysqld]
    datadir=/var/db/mysql
```

AND I'm specifying `datadir=/var/db/mysql` on the command line as well.

`/var/db/mysql` is owned by `mysql:mysql` and has permissions `750` as confirmed by the fact that `mysqld` has happily created the subdirectories `mysql` and `test`.

How else might the path to `host.frm` be specified?

Can I make the file by hand? (i.e. is it a text file?)

Running `mysql_install_db --user mysql --datadir /var/db/mysql` fails with the same error.

--update:
I've even tried starting the server from the `/var/db` directory to obviate the relative path `./mysql`; but that still fails. So the relative path starting point is something other than the directory where the program is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `mysql_install_db` to run for 5.5.38 on `FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE-p5 amd64` you have to supply: user, datadir and basedir. After `mysql_install_db` is finished, `mysqld` will find base and data directories without assistance. e.g.:

```
mysql_install_db  --user=mysql --basedir=/usr/local --datadir=/var/db/mysql
```

Please also note that the `=` chars for the parameters are required; but there is no error message if they are forgotten.

Comment: Results in segfault on FreeBSD 11.2 with mariadb103-server (10.3.7) ...

Comment: @Code4R7 hm.. segfault is a different sort of problem. The binary is actually crashing; so out of date libraries? exotic compiler options? Perhaps contact the port maintainer. 11.2 is still a little new.

Comment: I tried to install 10.3.7 via pkg, but eventually I managed to install 10.3.8 via ports.

Answer (score 1):

> Everything I can find suggests that host.frm should be created
>   first-start in the datadir.

Whatever suggested that to you is flat out wrong.  The system tables are created when you run `mysql_install_db`.

MariaDB official docs:  [Installing system tables (mysql_install_db)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/getting-started/installing-system-tables-mysql_install_db/).